# GRUB finds OS but doesn’t list it as a bootable option. Also not available in motherboard menu

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, arch-linux

I have been using EndeavourOS as my Linux distro for the past 4 months and it has worked fine.

I recently updated my BIOS and since then it is not an option. My PC is dual boot here is a quick outline of my drive setup:

- 2TB NVMe N0 (1TB EndeavourOS/1TB Debian).
- 4TB Windows.
- 4TB storage for Windows.
- 2TB storage for Windows.

Since the BIOS update I have been using Debian's GRUB install. When I run `os-prober` on Debian it shows Windows and EndeavourOS.

I run `update-grub` (Yes the `os-prober` in the config is active…) it lists Windows and EndeavourOS but at the boot screen I don't get the option. It also doesn't appear as an option in my UEFI.

(7950X 7900XTX 32GB DDR5 6400)

Output of `os-prober`:

```
root@debian:~# os-prober
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/nvme1n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows1:efi
/dev/nvme3n1p4:EndeavourOS Linux (rolling):EndeavourOS:linux
```

Output of `update-grub`:

```
root@debian:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-17-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-11-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-11-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme1n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found EndeavourOS Linux (rolling) on /dev/nvme3n1p4
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

The full `grub.cfg` from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=-1
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=-1
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/emerald-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-17-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-17-amd64-advanced-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-17-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-17-amd64-recovery-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-17-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-12-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-12-amd64-advanced-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-12-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-12-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-12-amd64-recovery-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-12-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-11-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-11-amd64-advanced-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-11-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-11-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-11-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-11-amd64-recovery-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-11-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-11-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-10-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-10-amd64-advanced-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-10-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-10-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-10-amd64-recovery-b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-10-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64 root=UUID=b8ae0629-86e9-4ee8-b8c3-20311b041780 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-10-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-6228-287A' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6228-287A
    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme1n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-C61A-9AD3' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C61A-9AD3
    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: It seems your EndevourOS was ionstalled in Legacy/"BIOS" mode

Comment: @ChanganAuto   This would explain why I had the old style grub (black and white and very simple) and how a bios update fried it. if it is possible i would like to get back into the system and update it to UEFI. How Would i go about this. i have looked at some things talking about duet but i am not fully sure

Comment: Typically you'd boot from it (or chroot) and install Grub for EFI. I don't know Endevour or Arch enough to detail the steps.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your rapid reply. the problem i have at the moment is i have no access to my endeavour OS (i can get files out but apart from that nothing) i am currently using grub from the Debian partition of that drive. i have already gathered the data i care about from the system but it seems that a full reinstall is required.

Comment: That's what chroot is for, as mentioned. But reinstalling properly is certainly an option. Keep in mind how it boots (the installation media) is how it installs. For guaranteed results make sure to disable CSM/Legacy mode in UEFI ("BIOS").